# Android - Show Selected Share Options

Tags: android, android-intent, share

I wanted to ask how can I show only selected share options in the popup share menu instead of all the available options in the popup menu. (Programmatically)

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean with the word selected? Somehow customize the menu appwide? Or systemwide?

Comment: @simekadam like i only want to show facebook share option not twitter or googleplus & othres..